# Remove Granting explicit consent using the "Grant Permissions" button in azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

when an app is registered in azure ad, to give permission to the app, we can grant consent to an application's delegated permissions on behalf of all the users in your tenant by clinking "Grant Permissions" button. How to undo this permission once it is given? Or, it can't be undo from azure portal once it is clicked? I am confused as it is always of same color and always ask "Do you want to grant...." dialog and "No" doesn't undo the action.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Shwan Tabrizi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396977/shawn-tabrizi) said, you can refer to the blog's way to remove the app from Enterprise Application.Because once you click Grant Permissions bottom, the app will be auto added into Enterprise applications and assign permissions to user. You can also choose which user to remove permission as following steps:

> 1.Sign in to the Azure portal with an account that's a global admin for the directory.
>
> 2.Select More services, enter Azure Active Directory in the text box, and then select Enter.
>
> 3.On the Azure Active Directory - *directoryname* blade (that is, the Azure AD blade for the directory you are managing), select Enterprise
>   applications.

[image]

> 4.On the Enterprise applications blade, select All applications. You'll see a list of the apps you can manage.
>
> 5.On the Enterprise applications - All applications blade, select an app.
>
> 6.On the appname blade (that is, the blade with the name of the selected app in the title), select Users & Groups.

[image]

> 7.On the appname - User & Group Assignment blade, select one of more users or groups and then select the Remove command. Confirm your
>   decision at the prompt.

[image]

Comment: Wayne, Thank you for the clear explanation with steps. @Shwan Tabrizi , Thank you for the blog.

Answer (score 4):

Revoking Tenant Wide Consent can be done through the Azure Portal.

See here: [Revoking Consent for Azure Active Directory Applications](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/revoking-consent-azure-active-directory-applications/)

> **Using the Azure Portal to Remove Tenant Wide Consent**
>
> If you are a tenant administrator, and you want to revoke consent for
>   an application across your entire tenant, you can go to the Azure
>   Portal.  Whether it be for a bunch of users who individually consented
>   or for an admin who consented on behalf of all the users, by simply
>   deleting the application’s service principal, you will remove all
>   delegation entries (the object used to store consent) for that
>   application. Think about removing the service principal like
>   uninstalling the application from your tenant.
>
> You could delete the service principal a bunch of different ways like
>   through Azure Active Directory PowerShell or through the Microsoft
>   Graph API, but the easiest way for the average administrator is right
>   through the Azure Portal.
>
> Navigate to the Enterprise Applications blade in the Azure portal:
>
> Then click “All Applications” and search for the application you want
>   to revoke consent for:
>
> When you click the application, you will be brought to an “Overview”
>   section, where a tempting button called “Delete” will be at the top.
>   Before you click this button,  you might want to take a peak at the
>   “Permissions” section to see the types of consent that was granted to
>   this application:
>
> Once you feel confident that you want to delete this application, go
>   back to “Overview” and click “Delete”!
>
> Viola! The app and all consent associated with that app is now gone.

There are some screenshots included in the actual blog post.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, that's a great blog post on this subject.  Nice work!

Comment: Thank you for your blog post. I have removed the application I consented to permissions from "myapps", but I can still login to this application without getting promted again to consent. When I look in the azure portal (enterprise applications -> my application -> permissions -> user consent) the permission is still granted to the user I tested with. Any idea?

Comment: What application? There are a class of Microsoft First Party applications which do not require consent.

Comment: It's an application I created and registered

Comment: After you removed the service principal connected to the application you must create a new service principal that is connected to the application otherwise people can't grand permissions anymore. Or an admin is unable to "Gran Permissions" again.